# Zurb Foundation 6 jQuery error

Tags: javascript, jquery, error-handling, zurb-foundation-6

Since I use Foundation 6 (6.1.2) I'm getting an error with my JavaScript/jQuery.

A simple

```
$(document).foundation({

accordion: {
    callback : function (accordion) {
        // do something
    }
}

});
```

doesn't work anymore and suddenly leads to an error:

*Uncaught TypeError: We're sorry, 'object' is not a valid parameter. You must use a string representing the method you wish to invoke.*

What am I doing wrong? I don't get it. Unfortunately, the Foundation 6 documentation is not the best and I wasn't able to find out how to handle this in Foundation 6...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can no longer do this in Foundation 6. Instead, do this:

```
$(window).on('down.zf.accordion', function(){
    console.log('accordion');
});
```

See events under http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html